# Getting right dates, but when I push to my months array, I get odd date output

Tags: javascript, typescript

So what I am trying to do, is create an array of months. But when I add months to my months array, I get

["January", "February", "March", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "December"]

as a result. But before I add to my array, the months print out fine.

- Mon Jan 01 1917 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
- Thu Feb 01 1917 00:00:00
  GMT-0500 (EST)
- Thu Mar 01 1917 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
- Sun Apr 01
  1917 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
- . . . Thu Nov 01 1917 00:00:00 GMT-0400
  (EDT)
- Sat Dec 01 1917 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

Notice April and November are in the 'raw' output.
I have checked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223183/javascript-print-previous-12-months-march-prints-twice) and others but they aren't as similar as I thought. Except for the 2 'March' issue.

If it matters, I'm using Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is my code:

```
getMonths(form: string = 'long'): string[] {
  if (form.toLowerCase() !== 'long' || form.toLowerCase() !== 'short') {
    form = 'long';
  }
  if (!this.yearSelected) { // sets default year to today
    this.yearSelected = this.today.getFullYear();
  }
  let months: string[] = [];
  let locale: string = "en-US";
  let month: Date;
  // console.log(this.selectedYear);
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i, 1);
    console.log(month);
    months.push(month.toLocaleString(locale, { month: form }));
    console.log(months[i]); // <-getting odd output from here
  }

  return months;
}
```

In the for loop I added the 1 to the 'day' parameter according the link I provided.  But my original code was

```
month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i);
```

if it matters. I also commented (for indication) the problematic output at the end of the for loop.

Edit: Just updated to Chrome 60.0.3112.78

Edit: removed typo toLocalLowerCase -> toLowercase()

Edit: So the problem has to do with daylight savings time.  Thanks to James' suggestion, I added 15 to month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i) therefore it is now month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i, 15).  I will look into using [UTC dates - Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

Comment: `this.yearSelected === Number('') || !this.yearSelected` can be shortened to `!this.yearSelected`

Comment: `form.toLowerCase() !== 'long' || form.toLocaleLowerCase() !== 'short'` is always `true`

Comment: This is working for me [in this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/cLOwlViH97qNoPXjweAn?p=preview). Also tested and works in the typescript playground. Edit: actually with the right date (1917) its showing the behaviour described

Comment: It's suspicious that the months that are messed up are those where DST begins and ends.

Comment: @0mpurdy I change your date to:       this.yearSelected = this.today.getFullYear() - 100;  That should replicate the error (It is when I select 1917 as the year).

Comment: @James I will confirm that daylight savings time is causing this headache.  Does that mean this is a problem in Javascript?

Comment: No, as Brian mentions in his answer it's swapping time zones.  You could "avoid" the problem by using the 15th of the month instead of the first.

Comment: @James Thanks, I tried with the 15th, and it works.  Kinda feels like a hack, but I just did a google search that lead me to Stackoverflow with timezone questions.  They suggest to use UTC (server time) to avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

- Thu Mar 01 1917 00:00:00 **GMT-0500 (EST)**
- Sun Apr 01 1917 00:00:00 **GMT-0400 (EDT)**

You're in different time zones, Date converts them to local time, which it does correctly, EDT of Sun Apr 01 1917, converted to EST, is March 31st 23:00:00, hence why you get March, March.

It's a pure TypeScript issue and how TypeScript is converting back to JavaScript, TypeScript does not have the same issue with UTCString instead of LocaleTimeString.

```
getMonths(form: string = 'long'): string[] {
  if (form.toLowerCase() !== 'long' || form.toLowerCase() !== 'short') {
    form = 'long';
  }
  if (!this.yearSelected) { // sets default year to today
    this.yearSelected = this.today.getFullYear();
  }
  let months: string[] = [];
  let locale: string = "en-US";
  let month: Date;
  // console.log(this.selectedYear);
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i);
    console.log(month);
    months.push(month.toUTCString(locale, { month: form }));
    console.log(months[i]); // <-getting odd output from here
  }

  return months;
}
```

returns: `["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]` as expected

Comment: I'll look into using UTC, unless there is a better way?

Comment: Where are the times being inputted from? You're changing it on the wrong side, the date should be coming to you in a consistent fashion if possible.

Comment: I'm making a dropdown date chooser.  Select year, then month, the day. And the years are within a range (18 years old - 100 years old) - hence 1917.  Also, from Angular which is client side.  If that is what you're asking.

Comment: never mind, I see it, weirdly enough your code runs fine locally on my machine though

Comment: actually, pure javascript is working, its a typescript issue, typescript is failing, but your original code works with changing toLocaleString to toUTCString()

Answer (score 0):

This is a Daylight Saving Time issue as Brian and James mentioned.  I used James' suggestion and added

```
month = new Date(this.yearSelected, i, 15); // 15 to avoid daylight savings time issues
```

which resolved the issue.  I also saw that I could use UTC dates in js which I will look into. Thanks.

Comment: edited my answer, if you did this in pure javascript it would have been fine, its a conversion error from TypeScript to javascript, you dont have to change everything to UTC date, just the call toLocaleString() to toUTCString(); this doesn't affect the underlying date at all, and none of the rest of your code has to change, no hacks of adding extra days or times has to be done that affect readability

Comment: Tried out your suggestion.  I like it, but I had to do month.toUTCString().substr(7, 4)); to extract the months. Otherwise I get an error stating that _supplied parametes do not match any signature of call target_