# Get the previous month name based on a supplied month name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to find the previous month name from a given month name. What is the best way of achieving this? Instead of passing current date month index, I need to pass the user's selected month name and get last month name.

For example:

1. If the user selects "January" as month name, it needs to return "December"
2. If the user selects "February" as month name, it needs to return "January"

Below is the sample code I am trying.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display the name of this month.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var d = new Date();
  var n = month[d.getMonth()-1];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Easiest in what sense? I mean, you could just have an object w/ month name keys and the previous month name values. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: Print previous 12 months -- "March" prints twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223183/javascript-print-previous-12-months-march-prints-twice)

Comment: @DaveNewton - I tried above code and trying to modifying that code for achieving my requirement.

Comment: @user120242 -  No, That is not my question. actual my requirement is..Instead of passing current date month i need to pass user selected month name and get last month name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uses an array of month names.  Lookup index and -1.  `||` is for if 0 use 12, so January wraps around to December.

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

function getLastMonth(month){return months[(months.indexOf(month) + 12 - 1) % 12]}

console.log(
  getLastMonth('January'),
  getLastMonth('November'),
  getLastMonth('December')
)
```

Comment: almost i got the solution. => this key is not taking in my .js file.

Comment: supporting IE I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way

```
function getPrev(month, prev){
 var months={}
 months[months['Jan']=1]='Jan'
 months[months['Feb']=2]='Feb'
 months[months['Mar']=3]='Mar'
 months[months['Apr']=4]='Apr'
 months[months['May']=5]='May'
 months[months['Jun']=6]='Jun'
 months[months['Jul']=7]='Jul'
 months[months['Aug']=8]='Aug'
 months[months['Sep']=9]='Sep'
 months[months['Oct']=10]='Oct'
 months[months['Nov']=11]='Nov'
 months[months['Dec']=12]='Dec'
 var ind = months[month]
 if(ind-prev<=0){
    return months[12+(ind-prev)]
 }
 return months[ind-prev];
}
console.log(getPrev('Apr',1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
var lastmonth="";
function getLastMonth(month){
lastmonth= months[(months.indexOf(month) + 11) % 12];
return lastmonth;
}

alert(getLastMonth('January'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to do the hard work for you:

```
let monthName = "January";
let parsedMonth = moment(monthName, "MMMM");
let prevMonth = parsedMonth.add(-1, "months");
let prevMonthName = prevMonth.format("MMMM");
```

Or, all condensed to a one-liner:

```
let prevMonth = moment("January", "MMMM").add(-1, "months").format("MMMM");
```

Here is a little [jsFiddle illustrating the concept](https://jsfiddle.net/2x7cthpr/).

If you want to go vanilla JS, then you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
var getPrevMonth = function (month) {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var index = months.indexOf(month);

  if (index < 0) return "Invalid month";

  return index === 0 ? months[months.length - 1] : months[index - 1];
};

var validPrevMonth = getPrevMonth("January"); // returns "December"
var invalidPrevMonth = getPrevMonth("Not a month"); // returns "Invalid month"
```

Again, a [jsFiddle illustrating the concept](https://jsfiddle.net/2x7cthpr/2/). Sticking to ES5 primarily, as that's what your question sample was written in. The use of moment just shows how much more terse it can be using a proper library, but the route you go is obviously your own decision.

Comment: how about plaing js withou library

Comment: That's always an option, but moment has become so widely accepted as the standard of managing dates that I barely even bother with manual date and time wrangling anymore. Besides, it's available on most CDN's and only 18.2kb if you want to manually include it. Hardly a bandwidth disaster, considering the titanic size of libraries these days.

Comment: @ChikkadamallaVenkataKrantiC I added a vanilla JS option as well, including a fiddle to show it in action. Note that I did error handling on invalid month names as well in case the supplied argument to the function is not a valid month name (either on casing or spelling).